# C++ console Save and load saved "games"

Tags: c++, console, save, restart

I have a grid of randomly generated numbers of size `gameSize`x`gameSize` (user input) which is contained within a vector of vectors. The user can enter  two co-ordinates (x, y) so that it changes a number within the grid to a predefined value.

So for example the user enters, X:0 Y:0 and:

```
{9, 7, 9}

{9, 6, 8}

{5, 1, 4}
```

becomes:

```
{0, 7, 9} <-- Changes position 0,0 to 0 (the predefined value)

{9, 6, 8} 

{5, 1, 4}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make it so the user can save the current board state and access it later on. I understand I need to somehow save the game (myGame) to a file, that way I can access it and load it into the console application again, essentially saving and restarting saved games, but I have no clue where to begin.

Comment: I would start with input and output file streams. If you have a textbook, there should be a section on file input and output. Then it's a matter of printing your series of numbers to a file and then reading them back in during your load

Comment: If you want to save/load a vector of vectors, you have to "bake" the inner vector sizes into the file format. Otherwise, the loader cannot recover the inner vectors appropriately. In your case, the inner vectors seem to have always the same size. This simplifies things: 1st I would use something else with fix size (e.g. a struct). 2nd File I/O for a vector of elements with fix size is much easier (and can be done with I/O streams straight forward as already suggested). However, the 2nd arg. will even apply to your current data model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fstream from standard library and add special methods to your game class, here is working example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Game
{
public:
    Game(int gameSize) : size(gameSize), field(size, vector<int>(size))
    {
        //Randomize(); //generate random numbers
//just filling example for test
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                field[i][j] = i * size + j;
            }
        }
    }

    Game(string filename) {
        Load(filename);
    }

    void Load(string filename) {
        fstream in;
        in.open(filename, fstream::in);
        in >> size;
        field.resize(size, vector<int>(size));
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                in >> field[i][j];
            }
        }
        in.close();
    }

    void Save(string filename) {
        fstream out;
        out.open(filename, fstream::out);
        out << size << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                out << field[i][j] << " ";
            }
            out << endl; //for user friendly look of file
        }
        out.close();
    }

private:
    int size;
    vector<vector<int>> field;
};

int main() {
    Game game(3);
    game.Save("game.txt");
    game.Load("game.txt");
    game.Save("game2.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to store game size in file for convinience of reading. It is good to add size property to your class and have another constructor if you want to load already stored game. Also it would be better if you add some checks that file is in appropriate format.
You can add all you logic of making turns into Game class as methods if they are not there already. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Save row by row, one row on each line:

```
void Game::save(std::istream& s)
{
    for (const auto& row: myGame)
    {
        for (auto cell: row)
        {
            s << cell << ' ';
        }
        s << '\n';
    }
}
```

Then read back line by line and create rows as you go:

```
void Game::load(std::istream& s)
{
    myGame.clear();
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(s, line))
    {
        std::istringstream cells(line);
        std::vector<int> row;
        int cell = 0;
        while (cells >> cell)
        {
            row.push_back(cell);
        }
        myGame.push_back(row);
    }
}
```

Separating the rows into lines means that you don't need to keep track of the lengths.
Using `istream&` and `ostream&` parameters means that you're not limited to using files but can use any stream, like `stringstream`, or `cin` and `cout`.
The latter can come in handy for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

For start you shall read about CSV format. Ask the user to set a name for your game and then save the array to a file like this:
- 1 save per line.
- line begins with Save name
- next two values represent size X and size Y.
- next values up to line ends represent array data.
Loading a save game performs like this:
- user is presented with a list of available saves
- user input which save intends to be loaded
- application loads the data like this:  search in file the line which contains the name it intends to load, read size x and size y to initialize an array of that size, load content into the array.

Comment: Why to use CSV for such a simple task? He can also use json for describing a game and loading it from server but I think it's beyond the scope of the project now. :)

Comment: Because he stated for console application... and CSV stands for Comma Separated Values.  If it was my application I would have used XML, there are libraries that interpret XML and make your life a lot easier while with CSV format it means you can learn something from this application.  Also in a single file you can store multiple saves... with your approach it stores 1 save/file.